# Floating div doesn't change its height to 100%

Tags: html, css

I want a floated div to have the full height of its parent.

Link to the JSFiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/Em6ms/2/

```
div.second {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    /* <- Problem: This does not work! */ }
```

That's how I want it look: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3646/yqfogsew_png.htm

I know there are lots of questions about this problem but not one answer worked on my specific case. I tried

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

and adding an additional div with the "clear: both" instruction.

Thank you!

Comment: It is because right now it is adjusting contents by itself as you have not specified height for div.first. If I will specify height for div.first, then it will automatically take its height.

Comment: you can't `height:100%` if the parent's height is not specified. same with a browser height div, you need to specify `html` and `body` to have a `height:100%` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the height of the parent div, you cannot set the child to have its height 100% relative to its parent. One way to fix this if the size of parent is not specified is using jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".second").css('height', $(".first").css('height'));
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6SXKa/)

Using pure javascript:

```
var firstHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].clientHeight-20;

var test = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0].style.height = firstHeight+"px";
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tg5gJ/1/)**

Comment: Is that way also possible when using pure JS?

Answer (score 1):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/Em6ms/6/)

you must set `height` for your parrent element (for example : `body`), then use `height:100%` !!

**CSS:**

```
body{
    height:500px;

}
div.first {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    max-width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px;
    padding: 1%;
}
div.second {
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    width: 18%;
    height:98%;
    top:1%;
    left:1%;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;
}
div.third {
    position:absolute;
    width:78%;
    height:98%;
    top:1%;
    right:1%;
    text-align: center;
    background:#e7e7e7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%;` means the element gets as high as its parent element. So you have to set the height of all parent elements to 100% too.

Your parent elements are not only `body, html` but also `.first`.

So just add

```
html, body, .first {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and it works!

But there is another problem too: You can't set the height of an element to 100% and also add some `padding`, `margin` or `border`. They need space so the element gets larger then 100%.

Comment: This increases the size: http://jsfiddle.net/JpgrQ/ Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: That's a different problem: Most browsers set some basic settings to `html` and `body`. You have to add `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` too. More about this at **[meyerweb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**.

Comment: Then apply the whole [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). The rest depends on your own margins, paddings and borders. They need space and make the element larger then 100%.

Comment: I have a question for you: why would you need a border for an element which has a height of 100%?

Comment: Why not? It should be a navigation.

Comment: It doesn't entirely work for me because it uses Javascript, but it doesn't seem like there is another possibility.

Comment: I thought you wanted the element to fill the whole page.